# Use USB to boot to specific partition of another drive?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, multi-boot, bootloader

Edit: The following paragraph is merely info on the origin of the problem, and reading it isn't required to answer the question.

I've been using a USB with Grub2 for a dual-boot between ParrotSec and Windows, both stored on different partitions of my HDD. The USB's job was to boot up to ParrotSec (stored on partition 8 of my HDD), and when it wasn't plugged in at boot-time, the BIOS skipped over the USB bootloader, thus eventually hitting the HDD bootloader (I left the Windows bootloader on partition one of the HDD just in case anything happened). However, my USB is now corrupt, resulting in only being able to boot Windows. I'm still on ParrotSec (I haven't restarted my PC, so I still have access to the Linux tools.)

So, the question is, how can I setup a USB drive to automatically boot to partition 8 of my HDD?

Edit: To simplify the question, I just need to put a bootloader on my USB to boot to `/dev/sda8`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to run `grub-install /dev/sdX` (/dev/sdX is you usb), this installs grub on the usb, and search grub files in `/boot/grub` in current system while booting.

Alternatively, you can mount the usb and run `grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/usb/boot /dev/sdX` (/mnt/usb is the mount point of you usb), this installs grub on the usb and grub images in the usb's /boot/grub.

Don't forget to run `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` or `grub-mkconfig -o /mnt/usb/boot/grub/grub.cfg` at the end.